# Python Pandas DataFrame converted to floats

Tags: python, pandas

I'm following an Ipython notebook, and the author did the following in order to replace all null values in a column through mean imputation.

**AUTHOR'S RESULT**

[image]

I copied the exact same code, but I got the following result:

**MY RESULT**

[image]

Am I missing something here? Why were the author's values rounded, while mine were not.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry thats what i meant

Comment: I'm not sure why his were rounded and yours were not, but you can use `round(average_petal_width, 2)` for the same result

Comment: Is the author's notebook hosted and linked somewhere? I suspect `pd.set_option('precision', 2)` is set.

Comment: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/rhiever/Data-Analysis-and-Machine-Learning-Projects/blob/master/example-data-science-notebook/Example%20Machine%20Learning%20Notebook.ipynb      ln 12